# Divs under each one

Tags: html, css

I have this website https://vitas.sk/objednat.php and i need to put everything like all that fields and text and submit in one column on MOBILE version that means something under 500px width. I ve tried probably all tuts on net but nothing work.

Comment: Have you try media queries ? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Yes i have no problem with media queries but with css to make it in one column all divs under each one.

Comment: please provide some code (HTML + CSS) for helping us to helping you.

Comment: I post exact link where is the problem https://vitas.sk/objednat.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you don't want your formularo use display:flex but display:block;
Next you want that your contactFormularo and inputs get 100% width.

and you want to use media queries like so :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

    .formularo{
       display:block;
    }

    .contactformularo {
        width:100%;
    }

    input[type="text"] {
        width:100;
    }
}
```

I let you see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)